# How are access tokens used in OpenID Connect for Single Sign On?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, tableau-api, openid-connect, bearer-token

My question is mainly about OpenID Connect's auth code flow and how it works after authentication and recieving an access_token and id_token.

Basically, I am working on an integration between a simple web application, a custom IdP (providing the OpenID Connect auth-code flow) and Tableau.  The goal is to allow for single-sign-on functionality by allowing a user to login to the web app and therefore have access to Tableau via a button inside the web app, all without having to log in to Tableau again since the webapp and Tableau are both using the same IdP.  I understand what OpenID Connect's documentation dictates around how to actually get an access_token, but I am strangely having difficulty determining how it is meant to be used.

After logging into the webapp through the IdP and the webapp receives an access_token, is it supposed to be sent to Tableau in future calls (being passed in the HTTP header as a bearer token) to access the system?  If so, how does Tableau actually validate that the access_token it has just received is still valid and active?  And if the user logs out of the webapp (and therefore the IdP), how does Tableau know that the access token is no longer active?  I would expect that on receiving an access token, Tableau would first send it to the IdP's /validate endpoint to confirm it is still good, but I have not been able to find any documentation verifying this (in both Tableau's and OpenID Connect's documentation).

If the access_token returned by the IdP is not meant for accessing Tableau after authentication, is the access_token from the IdP only meant to be used by Tableau to access the /userinfo endpoint on the IdP? As well, how does Tableau actually validate any incoming calls it receives?

Any insights into this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: let's clear things out, you have two applications, one is your web app and the other is tableau. And you have a common IDP for both. Your web app has a link to tableau. When you click that, you need to login to tableau without login prompt ? Question, have you configured tableau for OpenID Connect ?

Comment: Hi @KavinduDodanduwa, I don't have a Tableau install yet, I am preparing for this integration that should be happening soon.  The goal is to have Tableau configured for OpenID Connect so that when a user attempts to access Tableau through our webapp, they are already logged into it since they share the IdP.  I'm really just unclear about how Tableau confirms the user is logged into the IdP, I don't see this part of the flow documented in the OpenId Connect spec, I assume the access_token is involved but there is no mention of if and how it is used and what goes on behind the scenes.  Thanks!